# How to get iPhone's Unique Identifier (UDID) using Phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

How to get iPhone's Unique Identifier (UDID) using Phonegap ? Any code ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

var string = device.uuid;

PhoneGap api docs are here if you need any more info...
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Comment: Same here... device.uuid value is different when compared to iPhone's udid.

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot get UDID from phonegap API as of now.**

**Why?**

UDID is unique identifier for iOS devices and this is not there in other platforms such as Android, Windows etc. And hence phonegap cannot provide udid as its supposed to support all platforms.

**Solution** :

Phonegap API provides another unique identifier called `uuid`. This will be unique for each installation of the application.

**Drawback** : This unique key is a system generated one which is generated on each App boot(first launch of application). And hence you cannot determine the device properly. Uninstalling an application and installing it back again will regenerate a different udid.

URL : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: And how can I get the UDID? Something that makes the device unique?

Comment: u cannot get udid as of now. But you can use uuid which is a unique hash generated on each app install. But do note that a new uuid will be generated if the app is deleted and installed once more. Apple has removed all possible ways to track a phone/user through apps and hence any device spcific keys, we do not have access anymore..

Answer (score 0):

UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) Is on a per-app basis. identifies an app on a device. As long as the user doesn’t completely delete the app, then this identifier will persist between app launches, and at least let you identify the same user using a particular app on a device. Unfortunately, if the user completely deletes and then reinstalls the app then the ID will change.

UDID (Unique Device Identifier) A sequence of 40 hexadecimal characters that uniquely identify an ios device. This value can be retrieved through iTunes, or found using UIDevice -uniqueIdentifier. Derived from hardware details like MAC address.